# tar --remove-files behavior: delete after every file or after completion?

Tags: linux, tar

Pretty much in the title. I have a box with very little disk space left and lots of data. I want to add all of the files into a tar, deleting them as I go because there is clearly not enough space to get it all in without deleting the data. So, using the tar --remove-files option should work, if it deletes after it adds each file, not deleting after it completes the entire archive.

It's not sensitive data, just movies and music so I decided to run it anyway, so I'll find out in a while, but if anyone knows, it will certainly set my mind at ease if they could answer. If not, I'll post my findings once it's completed or failed miserably.

Comment: Since you have it running now, you can just monitor disk space or `ls` some files to see if they're still there.

Answer (score 0):

It is not written clearly in the manual page. From my experience, neither is true. It does not delete files after adding *immediately*, but seems to do so after some delay (time, or file size, or the number of files, I don't really know). It definitely started deleting before completion as my hard disk is not large enough to hold both all the original files and the tar.

For reference, I am using GNU tar 1.28.

OP, people on the Internet would definitely appreciate it if you did "post your findings" some 8 years ago [:)](https://xkcd.com/979/)

Answer (score -1):

I'm having a similar problem so I tried doing **strace** on **tar remove-files** acting on 2 files. In this case it seems like **unlink** is called by the system in the end, so that would mean that tar is *first* archiving and *then* deleting.
This is of course not a conclusive test, but at least a hint. You could try the same thing but with more files and look if tar acts differently in that case.

Comment: this is not an answer.